# Updating feature in ArcGIS REST service with Ajax?

Tags: arcgis-server, features, update, ajax

I have to modifiy an app. This app must update and add data to feature in an ArcGIS Server service. I know that with ArcGIS JavaScript API is very easy but this app is build with Leaflet and others things and I can't change.

I'm trying to do it with ajax, this is my code

```
$.ajax({  
            url: featureServiceUrl + "/updateFeatures",  
            dataType: 'json',  
            type: 'POST',  
            data: "features:"+poiToAdd+"&f=json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
                debugger;
                //  
                console.log('success');  
                console.log(data);  
                console.log(textStatus);  
                console.log(jqXHR)  
            },  
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                debugger;
                //  
                console.log('error'); //<-- the response lands here ...  
                console.log(jqXHR); //<-- the console logs the object  
                console.log(textStatus); //<-- the console logs 'parsererror'  
                console.log(errorThrown); //< -- the console logs 'SyntaxError {}'  
            },  
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {  
                debugger;
                //  
                console.log('complete');  
                console.log(jqXHR);  
                console.log(textStatus);  
            }  
        });
```

**PoiToAdd is the data to modify**, this data is correct because when I introduce it in this windows

[image]

the data is updated in my server, but with ajax code returns an error, that the data isn't correct. I also try with XMLHttpRequest
I have to say that this not is my code, but this work fine in other app from my company

```
update: function(updateFeature,callback){
    var updateparams = "features="+updateFeature+"&f=json";
    var updateurl=this.url+"/updateFeatures";
    var http;
    debugger;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        http=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        http=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    http.open("POST", updateurl, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

            if (callback) { callback(http.responseText); }
        }
    }
    http.send(updateparams);
}, //end UPDATE
```

**Here Updatefeatures is == to PoiToAdd** and this.url is the featureservice url, now when i execute this doesn't return any error,  but the data isn't updated

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved my problem - it was the next

my data had this simbol **"%" "&"** and **"+"** and this done that the ajax and XMLHttpRequest didn't work fine. One time i have changed this, the code work.

This symbol create an error because this symbol are reserved to the URL